# Is there a way to emulate symmetric multiprocessing over TCP/IP?

Tags: linux, multithreading, tcp, distributed-computing, smp

I have a number-crunching multithreaded software which creates a thread per CPU. For example, if `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep proc | wc -l` prints 24 than the software will create 24 threads.

I want to connect additional X machines with Y cpu cores so that the main sever on which the software runs will see 24+X*Y CPUs. It seems like I'm looking for implementation of SMP over IP.

Any existing solution for that?

Comment: Do you know how much do the threads communicate with each other? With even a modest amount of communication, if what you're asking was possible, it would likely significantly *decrease* the performance of the application, because of communication overhead. Only software designed to be run distributed will work well distributed.

Comment: @svick: thread Xi runs for t secs, then sends result to common queue on the main thread which takes the result from the queue and uses it.

Comment: SMP over TCP?  not a chance.  But read about _cluster computing_.  (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster)